# Will the Ubuntu tablet OS be flash-able from zip files?

Tags: android, tablet

Is it available for nexus only now? Will it be available for other tablets as well in flash-able zip files? Just like custom ROM for android flash from `cwm twrp`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a list of current ports:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices